# Python: Adding correct year to date value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm webscraping some data for a project and my dates are coming in like "Oct 04" (%b %d). I was wondering if anyone has found a pythonic way to add the *correct* year?

Say the data is like such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['Oct 01', 'Oct 11', 'Oct 21']})
```

I have the data in a dataframe, so I started with:

```
df.loc[:,"date"] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x+' 2020','%b %d %Y') for x in df["date"]]
```

But that is obviously going to be an issue when the new year rolls around (if I pick up new data from late December, it would not be data from Dec 28 2021, but Dec 28 2020). My first thought was to do something comparing the interval between Dec 28 2021, Dec 28 2021 and the current date, and use whichever is closer.

This as been a clunky endeavor so far, so any suggestions?

Comment: What is the *correct* year in this case for this example? You can use `datetime.datetime.now().year` for the year when the code is run....

Comment: Also, if the date is coming through every ten days (as it looks like from your example), you should be able to set up a date offset to generate the next date 10 days from your current date. An example would be `<last known date> + datetime.timedelta(days=10)`.

Comment: The name for this kind of problem is "business rules".  We can't answer it because we don't know what rules would be appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Well, I did give it a go: https://gist.github.com/nocibambi/833c6784d3f7d498191cbf75ee895175